# Find all derived types of generic class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic class and a derived class as following.

```
public class GenericClass<T> { ... }

public class DerivedClass : GenericClass<SomeType> { ... }
```

How do I find the derived class via reflection? I have tried both ways below, but doesn't seem to work.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(GenericClass<>).IsAssignableFrom(t));

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(GenericClass<>));
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var result = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType && 
                t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericClass<>));
```

Comment: Only goes 1 level deep, but anything more than that is a *huge* pain. +1 indeed!

Comment: Thanks for this, works great. One small thing; if you add a check for t.BaseType being null, then it's perfect.

Comment: Hmm, what type did you declare that didn't have a base type?  I can only think of System.Object

Comment: When I ran that directly, I got an object null exception when viewing the result. I didn't look into detail which type was causing the problem since I am pulling all the types from executing assembly. But once I check for t.BaseType being null, the error went away. Nonetheless, that was a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer below that will recursively find all the derived generic and non-generic classes.

Comment: And if your GenericClass takes multiple type parameters put one comma per additional parameter - `typeof(GenericClass<,>)` ,  `typeof(GenericClass<,,>)` and so on ..

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit more complex than that. t.BaseType may return null (e.g. when t is an interface). Also note that the [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) method does not work for generic types! If you are dealing with a generic type you should use the GetTypeDefinition method. I recently blogged about [**how to get all derived types of a class**](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/05/get-all-derived-types-of-class.html). Here's an IsSubclass method that works for generics, too:

```
public static bool IsSubclassOf(Type type, Type baseType)
{
    if (type == null || baseType == null || type == baseType)
        return false;

    if (baseType.IsGenericType == false)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType == false)
            return type.IsSubclassOf(baseType);
    }
    else
    {
        baseType = baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    }

    type = type.BaseType;
    Type objectType = typeof(object);
    while (type != objectType && type != null)
    {
        Type curentType = type.IsGenericType ?
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : type;
        if (curentType == baseType)
            return true;

        type = type.BaseType;
     }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm responding to Hans Passant about "t.BaseType.IsGenericType". t.BaseType may return null if t is an interface for example.

Answer (score 2):

Because I needed to recursively find all derived types I wrote this code and will share with anyone who may need it:

```
    public void ListAllDerviedTypes()
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(TableAdapter);
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(entityType.Assembly.Location);
        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

        List<Type> results = new List<Type>();
        GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(types, typeof(SiteAndSectorsTable<>), ref results);

        foreach (var type in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        }
    }

    private static void GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(Type[] types, Type type1, ref List<Type> results)
    {
        if (type1.IsGenericType)
        {
            GetDerivedFromGeneric(types, type1, ref results);
        }
        else
        {
            GetDerivedFromNonGeneric(types, type1, ref results);
        }
    }

    private static void GetDerivedFromGeneric(Type[] types, Type type, ref List<Type> results)
    {
        var derivedTypes = types
            .Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                        t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type).ToList();
        results.AddRange(derivedTypes);
        foreach (Type derivedType in derivedTypes)
        {
            GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(types, derivedType, ref results);
        }
    }


    public static void GetDerivedFromNonGeneric(Type[] types, Type type, ref List<Type> results)
    {
        var derivedTypes = types.Where(t => t != type && type.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();

        results.AddRange(derivedTypes);
        foreach (Type derivedType in derivedTypes)
        {
            GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(types, derivedType, ref results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ta - just used your pattern locally here to ensure we're testing all particular implementations of a (generic) base class and it's worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

An improved (shorter) version of Kim's answer:

```
    public List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(Type baseType)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(baseType.Assembly.Location);
        Type[] typesInAssembly = assembly.GetTypes();

        var results = new List<Type>();
        GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(typesInAssembly, baseType, ref results);

        return results;
    }

    private static void GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(Type[] types, Type baseType, ref List<Type> results)
    {
        Type[] derivedTypes;

        if (baseType.IsGenericType)
            derivedTypes = types.Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseType).ToArray();
        else
            derivedTypes = types.Where(t => t != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToArray();

        results.AddRange(derivedTypes);

        foreach (Type derivedType in derivedTypes)
            GetAllDerivedTypesRecursively(types, derivedType, ref results);
    }
```